# Need to send collection in a GET Request to my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a scenario where I need to send multiple ProductCodes in a GET Request to my Web API.  In my asp.net web api controller is there a way that I can make the parameter of my Action method be of type `List<int> ProductCodes`. I am assuming no, I have to pass them like this `?ProductCodes=a,b,c` and then accept it as list of string of `ProductCodes`.  Please let me know if there is a better way.

I  am getting null at code side

```
[HttpGet] 
[ActionName("product-cache-deletion")] 
public HttpResponseMessage ProductCacheDeletion(List<string> ProductCodeList) { 
    //...
}
```

Which I call like

```
http://localhost:59956/api/manuals/product-cache-deletion?ProductCodeList=a,b,c
```

but every time value will be null for `ProductCodeList`

Comment: [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("product-cache-deletion")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ProductCacheDeletion(List<string> ProductCodeList)
        {} 
this is the api method which i m trying to call like-
http://localhost:59956/api/manuals/product-cache-deletion?ProductCodeList=a,b,c

but everytime value will be null for ProductCodeList

Comment: If you duplicate query string parameters browsers will interpret them as an array, maybe web api does too. Try `?ProductCodes=a&ProductCodes=b`,etc.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try like below in which you can pass multiple value as well as
>   multiple parameters easyly. Hope it will help you.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { ProductCodes: "a,b,c" },// By this way you can pass multiple parameters too
        success: function (rsp) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in request multiple param with one name ProductCodeList

http://localhost:59956/api/manuals/product-cache-deletion?ProductCodeList=a&ProductCodeList=b&ProductCodeList=c

Comment: I upvoted, as I have tested this and works, but can you provide the documentation or rfc where I can find this is the "official" way?

Answer (score 0):

In your action, set the [FromURI] attribute like so:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ProductCacheDeletion([FromUri] IEnumerable<string> ProductCodeList)
```

If I remember rightly, I think the [FromUri] bit is the main reason that you are getting null.
Otherwise you would end up with a single entry in your list of "a,b,c".

And then your URL, you can specify each post code list as a separate query string parameter like so:

```
/product-cache-deletion?ProductCodeList=a&ProductCodeList=b&ProductCodeList=c
```

When I have done this, I've made the parameter called the singular version of what I was passing in, so the URL read more intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FromUri] attribute which will force the api to read the query string as a list

```
[HttpGet] 
[ActionName("product-cache-deletion")] 
public HttpResponseMessage ProductCacheDeletion([FromUri]List<string> ProductCodeList) 
{ 
    //...
}
```

Then call the api with the same parameter name foreach item in the array

```
http://localhost:59956/api/manuals/product-cache-deletion?ProductCodeList=a&ProductCodeList=b&ProductCodeList=c
```

Read more about the attribute [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)